# Pvlib-Python Datetime Error 'Is not convertible to datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, unidata, pvlib, thredds

I am trying to access forecast data by using the PVLib-Python command `model.get_data(longitude, latitude, start, end)` or `model.get_processed_data(latitude, longitude, start, end)` (where `model = GFS()`) but I am getting this error: TypeError: `<class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'> is not convertible to datetime`.

I have already used many versions of the PVLib-Python but hasn't worked though. Also, I checked the official documentation but they present the same error in te document (page 121 to 124 of the paper here https://readthedocs.org/projects/cwhanse-pvlib-python/downloads/pdf/latest/).

Here is some of the basic code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pvlib.forecast import GFS, HRRR_ESRL, NAM, NDFD, HRRR, RAP 

latitude = 32.2
longitude = -110.9 
tz = 'America/Phoenix'

start = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today(), tz=tz) # today's date
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=7) # 7 days from today

model = GFS()

data = model.get_data(latitude, longitude, start, end)

data.plot(figsize=(12,12), subplots=True)
```

Comment: I just tried to run the above code snippet and it ran fine

Comment: Have you tried updating the siphon package?

Comment: For real? Can I ask which version of PVLib and also Siphon do you have, @AdamJensen? I tried PVLib 0.7.1 and Siphon 0.8.0, the most recent.

Comment: pvlib is 0.7.1 and Siphon is 0.8.0, so the exact same ones as you have. I get 11 variables and they plot nicely. Strange..

Comment: Oh boy, truly strange, but hey, thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I just tried it on another laptop and recreated your error. I'll take a look tomorrow to see what is going on...

Comment: I am also trying that and using other environments to run the code. I think it could be a crash in the recent pvlib release but I keep getting that error in other versions and also they show that same error in the documentation. Thank you very much for taking the time and your help, I am very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs in the datetime class, which is in the *cftime* pacakage. I get the error when I use cftime version 1.1.1.2, whereas when I do not get the error when I use version 1.0.3.4.

The easiest solution is to down grade your *cftime* pacakge. If your using Anaconda, then running the following command in an Anaconad prompt will do that:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cftime=1.0.3.4
```

There is some discusion on the topic on cftime's project website: https://pypi.org/project/cftime/

**Update**: the bug has been **fixed in the new pvlib release pvlib-0.7.2**. The bug is described further here: https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/895

Comment: YES! With that and your help it works perfectly well. Thanks a lot for taking your time and for helping me with that. Excellent, I am truly grateful! :)